# How do I prevent Extreme Tux Racer from changing my desktop resolution?

Tags: 11.10, resolution, games, screen

I installed the [Extreme Tux Racer](http://extremetuxracer.com/) game in Ubuntu 11.10 from the Software Center but my screen expands abnormally after I start a game.

#### Before starting the game:

[image]

#### After closing the game

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extreme Tux Racer starts by default with a resolution width of 800 pixels.
Exiting the game should restore your original resolution, but unfortunately it seems the game is crashing when you close, before it can re-resize your display

There is a workaround. You can set a custom game resolution by editing lines in `~/.etracer/options`:

```
set x_resolution X
set y_resolution Y
```

where `X` and `Y` are your desired game width and height. If you set them to your normal resolution dimensions, the game should never "enlarge" your screen to begin with.

Comment: You're right :)

Comment: Thanks! After editing the options file as per my original screen resolution, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the game executable in simple script:

```
#!/bin/sh

# get current resolution
PREV_RES=$(xrandr -q | grep '^ *[0-9]*x[0-9]*' | awk '/\*/{print $1}')

# start the game
/path/to/my/game    # <---- CHANGE THIS !!!!

# restore previous resolution
xranrd -s $PREV_RES
```

Then use this script to start the game.
I didn't test it on multi-monitor configuration. There might be better way to get current resolution than parsing xrandr.